# I want to remove el-upload close icon

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to remove el-upload close icon

```
.el-upload-list__item:hover .el-icon-close {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, from where do you want to remove it? Please provide more context or a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)?
In this case maybe you can try:

```css
::v-deep .el-upload-list__item:hover .el-icon-close {
  display: none !important;
}
```